# Could not select date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm using this code, but could not select any date in datepicker. Why? When I change months then I can select dates. I used `disableFunc` to disable next 3 days and sundays in calendar. When I remove that `disableFunc` I can select dates. Any solution?

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField : '_dob',
        ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
        button : '_dob_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
        disableFunc: function(date)
        {
            var first_day = new Date();
            var second_day= new Date();
            var third_day= new Date();

            first_day.setDate(first_day.getDate());
            if(first_day.getDay()===0)
            {
                 first_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+1);
            }

            second_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+1);
            if(second_day.getDay()===0)
            {
                second_day.setDate(first_day.getDate()+2);
            }

            third_day.setDate(second_day.getDate()+1);
            if(third_day.getDay()===0)
            {
                third_day.setDate(second_day.getDate()+2);
            }


            var flag1 = first_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && first_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && first_day.getYear()===date.getYear();
            var flag2 = second_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && second_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && second_day.getYear()===date.getYear();
            var flag3 = third_day.getDate()===date.getDate() && third_day.getMonth()===date.getMonth() && third_day.getYear()===date.getYear();

            if(date.getDay() === 0 || flag1 || flag2 || flag3)
            {  return true; }

        }
    });
```

Comment: If you troubleshoot line by line, what line caused the unexpected behavior?

Comment: `return true;` causes the unexpected behavior, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution -

If you disable the current date then only this problem arises. i tried to remove current date from disabled dates and it works fine.

If you still want to disable current date then visit this link and follow the instructions.

Disable current date in dynarch popup calendar

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might be helpful to you. It is suggested to avoid using == or ===

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript])

Comment: Note in [SO] link only answers are not welcome. Try to give some explanation. And in case the question is quite similar, then the question can be closed as duplicated.